# VSCode no completa los bucles en Python

Tags: python, vscode

estoy usando Python con VSCode y todo bien asta hace un tiempo, el vscode no esta mostrandome sugerencias para autocompletar los bucles, me refiero a que el editor completa la sintaxis principal y de ahi yo lo completo con lo que quiero, es muy raro porque hasta hace poco si lo hacia, no he instalado nada ni movido ninguna configuracion.
por ejemplo yo escribia "for" y en las sugerencias me daba la opcion de autocompletar con el "in" etc.
incluso instale Pycharm para ver si era cosa del editor pero en primera instancia tampoco sale (o quiza no lo haya configurado) recalco que en vscode uso PyLance

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Comment: No creo que nunca te vaya a sugarir poner un `in` para autocompletar un `while` ¿No te estarás confundiendo con un `for`?

Comment: @abulafia si tienes razón ya lo corregí jaja lo siento

Comment: Solo fue un error ortografico, el problema sigue siendo el mismo :(

Comment: @JM499 me pasa muy a menudo iniciar VS Code y que no estén las extensiones activadas, si cuentas con una extensión para Python, abre un archivo .py y se debería de activar, si no se activa, ve al marketplace de extensiones, desactiva y activa la extensión. Si no tienes ninguna extensión, debes instalar una, ya que es normal que no haya sugerencias de autocompletado si no tienes la extensión apropiada

Comment: @anythingg si si tengo todo instalado, borré profundamente y volvi a instalar, desde el propio vsc hasta las extenciones y nada

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Segunda edición**: no es un *bug*, sino una característica suprimida en las versiones nuevas.
**Editado**: dejo al final la primera respuesta que había dado inicialmente.

---

Al parecer, el autocompletado de *snippets* daba bastantes problemas en algunos casos, por lo que han optado por quitarlos:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14781

Como solución ofrecen los [snippets de la extensión](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/2020.12.424452561/snippets/python.json) para que los copies en los [snippets de usuario](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

Otra opción es volver a instalar la versión anterior o instalar algunas de las extensiones con *snippets* para python:

[image: instalar versión vieja]

---

Con `pylance`, la extensión recomendada para python en vscode, el autocompletado funciona con el tabulador:

- primer tab: completa
- segundo tab: saca el *snippet*

[image: snippet while]

[image: snippet for]

Comment: Si amigo, uso pylance y justo esa señal que te aparece a ti al escribir el while en las sugerencias (el cuadrado blanco vacío) ya no me sale antes si me salía ahora ya no y no tengo idea del porqué, ya desisntale, borre residuales de todo, volví a instalar y no se solucionó. :(